# pyautogui.screenshot() at the same screen with diferent pixels

Tags: qt, screenshot, qtstylesheets, pyautogui, autotest

I use `pyautogui` to write the auto-gui test tool for `Debian9` desktop application written by  `Qt5.9.2`. The background of application was filled with many **PNG** images by `qss`. I capture the screenshot by `pyautogui.screenshot()` and compare the pixels by `pyautogui.getpixel()`. I found the **sceenshots** captured by `pyautogui.screenshot()` may be slightly different with **1 pixel**, such as:

```
Different image at pos[528, 1228], pixel1[21, 21, 22], pixel2[21, 21, 24]
Different image at pos[528, 1414], pixel1[94, 94, 94], pixel2[93, 93, 93]
Different image at pos[529, 1414], pixel1[94, 94, 94], pixel2[93, 93, 93]
Different image at pos[530, 1414], pixel1[94, 94, 94], pixel2[93, 93, 93]
Different image at pos[531, 1414], pixel1[94, 94, 94], pixel2[93, 93, 93]
Different image at pos[812, 1225], pixel1[55, 55, 55], pixel2[54, 54, 54]
Different image at pos[812, 1228], pixel1[23, 23, 24], pixel2[23, 23, 25]
Different image at pos[812, 1229], pixel1[13, 13, 14], pixel2[12, 13, 14]
Different image at pos[812, 1230], pixel1[13, 13, 14], pixel2[13, 13, 15]
```

I don't know it's casused by `Qt` or `pyautogui`.

**Updated**
I find the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654009/pyautogui-image-recognition-slight-issue-with-pixel-color-matching) without the convinced answer.

Comment: `pyautogui` is a bunch of wrappers around different libraries and platform-specific code. You could investigate more by stepping in with your debugger to see what functions `pyautogui` uses to get pixel data and take screenshots -- perhaps these underlying functions have known quirks.

Comment: On `Debian Linux`, `pyautogui` use `scrot` command to take screenshots.